# POJO to an XML string in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-serialization

I would like to create a REST interface for my Java Google App Engine program. I figured I would start by generating some XML from my POJOS. However, it seems that XStream is bitten by GAE's restrictions.

What can I use to generate an XML string in Google App Engine?

Thanks.

Edit 1:
Here is the beginning of the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract    java.lang.String com.mydomain.client.ObjectService.sendObject(com.mydomain.client.models.myobject)' threw an unexpected exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.SerializablePermission enableSubclassImplementation)
```

Comment: What are the restrictions that forbid XStream? If you tell us that, maybe we can suggest a library that wouldn't fall foul of the same restrictions.

Comment: Incidentally, Spring-WS uses the term POX for "Plain old XML"..... POJO to POX .... I quite like it.

Comment: Updated post to include the "SerializablePermission" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is caused by a java.io.SerializablePermission, which according the javadoc is for allowing:

> Subclass implementation of
>   ObjectOutputStream or
>   ObjectInputStream to override the
>   default serialization or
>   deserialization, respectively, of
>   objects

XStream might be using Object streams under the covers, and falling foul of this permission not being granted.

Does Google App Engine actually have a whitelist, or just a set of restricted permissions? JAXB2 doesn't use Object streams, so have you actually tried that?

Answer (score 1):

For the same restriction (a patch is underway however) I ended producing JSON using org.json library. Also JAXB seems not to be in the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) - it will give you XML, JSON, and lots more via REST; all using annotated methods.

It works for me, however there are some caveats:

See [here](http://lqd.hybird.org/journal/?p=123) and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/running_the_jersey_webapp_on)

Comment: Do you use Jersey on Google App Engine?