# XML serialization for Groovy classes

Tags: java, xml, spring, google-app-engine, groovy

For an application build on `Spring MVC` + `Groovy` + `Google App Engine` i need simple XML serializer/marchaller.

I'v tried:

- `XStream` - it doesn't work on Google App Engine, because it uses restricted (at GAE) classes
- `Jaxb2` - it doesn't work with Groovy classes, because groovy class have additional  (hidden) fields (like `metaClass`, etc)
- `XmlBeans` as I understand can be used only for deserializing from XML to Java Beans
- `Castor` seems to be big overhead (i don't need any XMLSchema and so on)

I want to just dump class to the corresponding XML, and i want to configure tag names using some simple config (java annotations, for ex), without XMLSchema/DTD

So, requirements is:

- usable at Google App Engine
- no XMLSchema/DTD
- simple configuration
- fast
- it's enough only object->xml
- maven2 support
- groovy support (or manually configured list of used fields)
- (optional) spring integration

Can anyone recommend me an good tool for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011498/POJO-to-an-XML-string-in-Google-App-Engine-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a lib which fits your requirements, but you could take a look into that list: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/xml-serializers-for-java/

e.g. the simple lib is a good candidate